# Mocking the CAL EventAggregator with Moq

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using the [Composite Application Library](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF)'s event aggregator, and would like to create a mock for the [IEventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707867.aspx) interface, for use in my unit test.

I'm planning on using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) for this task, and an example test so far looks something like this:

```
var mockEventAggregator = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
var mockImportantEvent = new Mock<ImportantEvent>();
mockEventAggregator.Setup(e => e.GetEvent<SomeOtherEvent>()).Returns(new Mock<SomeOtherEvent>().Object);
mockEventAggregator.Setup(e => e.GetEvent<SomeThirdEvent>()).Returns(new Mock<SomeThirdEvent>().Object);
// ...
mockEventAggregator.Setup(e => e.GetEvent<ImportantEvent>()).Returns(mockImportantEvent.Object);

mockImportantEvent.Setup(e => e.Publish(It.IsAny<ImportantEventArgs>()));

// ...Actual test...

mockImportantEvent.VerifyAll();
```

This works fine, but I would like know, if there is some clever way to avoid having to define an empty mock for every event-type my code might encounter (SomeOtherEvent, SomeThirdEvent, ...)? I could of course define all my events this way in a [TestInitialize] method, but I would like to know if there is a more clever way? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this one:

```
var mockEventAggregator = new Mock<IEventAggregator>{ DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
```

will make the mockEventAggregator return mocks for all nested objects.